How to use rigid scan with dummy atoms in gaussian?
I am trying to use rigid scan using gaussian 09. In my case, there are three water molecules and I have placed a dummy atom at the centroid of the three water molecules. For simplicity, I want to increase the bond lengths between the dummy atom and one O atom (I require a more complex scan). Here is my gaussian input,
%chk=scan_test.chk
# scan hf/3-21g

Title Card Required

0 1
X
O      1  R1
H      1  R2             2  A1
H      1  R3             2  A2             3  D1
O      2  R4             3  A3             4  D2
H      3  R5             4  A4             5  D3
H      4  R6             5  A5             6  D4
O      5  R7             6  A6             7  D5
H      6  R8             7  A7             8  D6
H      7  R9             8  A8             9  D7

R1     1.5 10 0.1
R2     1.21599
R3     2.36971
R4     2.79817
R5     2.11128
R6     3.75928
R7     2.80936
R8     2.13995
R9     4.09006
A1    37.21644
A2    17.66843
A3    18.69606
A4   143.56297
A5    14.26141
A6    19.23869
A7   131.09242
A8     8.00812
D1   -71.50951
D2   138.83131
D3   -51.19509
D4  -104.43605
D5   110.38219
D6   -36.56434
D7   111.01192



The calculation does not give any error, but the output shows that the scan has been performed between the first O(O2) and the first H(H3). Also, other bond lengths have been changed.
So,

Is there any way to incorporate dummy atoms into this scan?
Why other bond lengths are changed?


This appears to be possible, based on this chem SE answer. However, I vaguely remember dummy atom scans only working as of G16, so maybe it's not possible with G09.

This can be true. I was trying to set up this job with Gview and it showed invalid job status in redundant editor.

I have not created the input with GView but by hand. This is tedious for large geometry but possible. The sample input example shows multi-dimensional RIGID SCAN or UNRELAXED SCAN. I think this serves the purpose.
I have put a dummy atom at the centroid between three O water atoms. I have made the z-matrix in such a way that only the bond parameters I want to scan are put together. Also, scanning these parameters do not change other bond parameters.

Title Card Required

0 1
X
O      1  R12
O      1  R13             2  A312
O      1  R14             2  A412             3  D1
H      2  R25             1  A521             4  D2
H      2  R26             5  A625             1  D3
H      3  R37             1  A731             2  D4
H      3  R38             7  A837             1  D5
H      4  R49             1  A941             3  D6
H      4  R410            9  A1049            1  D7

R12     1.61 3 0.1
R13     1.61 3 0.1
R14     1.61 3 0.1
R25     0.90 4 0.03
R26     0.96
R37     0.90 4 0.03
R38     0.97
R49     0.90 4 0.03
R410    0.97
A312    120.0
A412    120.0
A521    48.7
A625    90.0 3 10.0
A731    49.0
A837    90.0 3 10.0
A941    50.0
A1049   90.0 3 10.0
D1      -179.9
D2      -176.2
D3      -132.9
D4      176.3
D5      -116.0
D6      -179.9
D7      130.4



So, I am keeping all the dihedrals and some of the bond lengths and angles fixed here. While others are changing.
